# Notation of a random variable, $\xi$ versus $X$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, notation

I'm reading Kallenberg's foundations of modern probability 2nd Ed (Early chapters). He uses $\xi$ as the notation for a random variable whereas almost all other books (e.g. Durrett's probability:Theory and Examples) use $X$ as the notation for a random variable. I think when it comes to stochastic processes, he then switches to $X_t$.

I'm just curious what the reasoning behind his use of Greek alphabets is? Is this the consensus for some publications? Is this like a historic thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no particular reason to use either $X$ or $\xi$ and there is no real consensus which symbol one should use. It is rather a matter of convenience:

> It is convenient to denote a random variable similarly to, but differently from, its values.

Since the most commonly used symbols for *unknown* (*real*) values are $x,y,z$, and since it is convenient to be able to write expressions like

> A random variable takes a given value

by a coincise formula like

$$X=x,$$

the habit took hold to denote random variables by $X,Y,Z$. It is particularly used in textbooks, where it is necessary to distinguish a variable from its values as this distinction may not be apparent from context to the reader. In research papers it is not unusual to use $x$ for random variables and write instead something like

$$x=x_0.$$

This holds mostly for real-valued random variable, but it does not make much sense for random variables with special values:

> the notation for random variables is usually superseded by the standard notation for the objects they describe.

That is, it is unusual to denote a random angle by $X$, and one would use instead $\theta$ or even $\omega$.

Greek letters are be introduced because

> the notation for random variables is usually superseded by the standard notation for other objects, if the two are conflicting

It is quite common to use $X$ for topological spaces or measurable/measure space, so in this case you would not use $X$ to denote a random variable with values in some such space, and prefer $X$ to indicate the space. The random variable could then be named $\xi$, and one could  write $\xi=x$ to indicate that the r.v. $\xi$ takes the value $x\in X$.

Finally, there is a tendency to avoid capitalization, as formulas become cumbersome to read. The reasonable alternative is to use Greek letters, since they can still be reasonably paired with Latin ones.